# How to save the access token inside the code level of apache camel so it doesn't need to call the auth api if it's existing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm using apache camel to call a third-party API but it needs to call the /authenticate API before sending requests to other paths? Instead of always calling the /authenticate API I would like to store it inside a variable then when another request is made it would check if there is an existing token. If you have any suggestions let me know. Thank you

Comment: Use a bean that stores the value. Call the bean.

Comment: For this I tend to use a class with a name such as "SessionTokenStore". In here would be a static class variable such as a String. You can create a getter method to access this var such as: .bean(SessionTokenStore.class, "getSessionToken(*)"). Pass in your exchange and set the exchange body to be the token.